# Convert point layer to text in v8 design file

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, fme-transformer

I have a shape file point layer with field  "name" having attribute values e.g. 'city name'. I want these attribute values as text in v8 design file using FME.
Any help please.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use the **LabelPointReplacer** transformer, using the name field as the attribute to use to define the label.

Then writing it to DGN should give you text.

You can use the attribute *idgs_justification* to specify the text justification - i.e. where the text is positioned in relation to the original point. Either the Readers/Writers manual or [this article](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/16546/text-justification.html) on the FME Knowledgebase shows what values to use (for example 7 is centre/centre, 2 is bottom-left).

If it's multi-line text and you want text nodes then that would be more complicated. Each line of text would need to go into a separate list entry. [This article](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1539/writing-microstation-dgn-text-nodes-with-fme.html) gives a good example of how to do that.